# setNativeProps on a component property

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to manipulate prop value in my component which taken from the lib `react-native-vector-icons` so Its icon component with property of `color` I want to manipulate the `color` without using the state but with `setNativeProps` I tried this:

```jsx
this.likeIcon.setNativeProps({
    color:'red'
})


   <IconEn ref={like => this.likeIcon = like}  color={'#900'}  name="thumbs-up" />
```

as described in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html) but it gives my an error:

> "You are setting the style '{color: ...}' as a prop. You should nest it in a style object E.g. '{style: {color: ... }}'"

so I tried to style the component using `style={{color: '#900'}}` and manipulate the `style` prop but this component wont work like that and it need to receive `color` prop as the color

Comment: `style={{color: #900}}` should have been `style={{ color: '#900' }}`

Comment: yes it was inside quotes but this component has `color` prop so it doesnt work

Comment: Have quick read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#composite-components-and-setnativeprops). Might be cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `IconEn` to use the parent's color property, you can do so like this:

```
<IconEn ref={like => this.likeIcon = like}  style={{color: this.props.color}}  name="thumbs-up" />
```